# Why isn't it possible to append an element of a string by its index number to a new string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, append

I had been programming previously in Python. I have been trying to replicate a similar approach in C++.

**What I intend to do :** Take the number of cases "N" from the user through "cin" and for each case take a string input "str". Iterate through every index of the string "str", print the elements of even index locations together followed by a space and then the elements of odd index locations.

An example case of what I would like to achieve would be:
User Input : *Aeronautics*
Output : *Arnuis eoatc*

**The program shown below is my C++ code:**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int N;
    cin>>N;
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
        string str;
        cin>>str;
        string even;
        string odd;
        for(int j=0; j < str.size(); j++){
            if (j % 2 == 0){
                even.append(str.at[j]);
            }
            else if (j % 2 != 0){
                odd.append(str.at[j]);
            }
        cout<<even<<" "<<odd<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**The error messages shown below where obtained directly from my compiler when I tried to run the code mentioned above:**

```
solution.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
solution.cc:20:37: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function     type>[int]’ for array subscript
                 even.append(str.at[j]);
                                     ^
solution.cc:23:36: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function     type>[int]’ for array subscript
                 odd.append(str.at[j]);
                                    ^
```

From what I can understand, the compiler says that I cannot append an index element of a string to another string in this manner. I tried to search for reasons why this isn't possible in C++ on other forums, but could not get an answer. Can you please enlighten me why ?

Comment: Try `even.append(str[j]);`.

Comment: it should be at(), not at[]

Comment: I tried both () and []. They both give me compile time errors. I believe the problem is somewhere else !

Comment: I recommend including `<string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of errors.

1. `str.at[j]` needs to be `str.at(j)` or `str[j]`.
2. The version of `string::append()` you are using needs another argument.

   ```
   basic_string& append( size_type count, CharT ch );
   ```

   You need to use:

   ```
   even.append(1, str[j]);
   ```

   and

   ```
   odd.append(1, str[j]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `.append` overload that takes a single char (you also have syntax error). There are several ways you could do this.

`even += str[j];
...
odd += str[j];`

Or with bounds checking

`even += str.at(j);
...
odd += str.at(j);`

Or if you still want to use `.append`

`even.append(1, str[j]);
...
odd.append(1, str[j]);`